# Installation of package rj to work with the Statet plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, r

I've been trying to install the rj package for R, but i'm having the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-2.11.1-x64\bin>R CMD INSTALL --no-test-load \M\rj_0.5.2-1.tar.gz
* installing to library 'C:\Users\MyUser\Documents/R/win64-library/2.11'
* installing *source* package 'rj' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dirname(this$RuntimeLib)
  error: a character vector argument expected
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'rj'
* removing 'C:\Users\MyUser\Documents/R/win64-library/2.11/rj'
```

Note that i'm using windows 7 64 as well as Java and R 64 bits (currently i have no 32 bits installation of java).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm don't know what was appening, but i removed R, removed eclipse and then reinstall them, first r, the rJava package, then the rJ package and then i installed the Statet plugin in eclipse, and all worked out well.

I have also removed the .eclipse folder in c:\users\myuser\

For the r installation i made a complete install (i386 and x64).
For the eclipse x64 only.

Hope this helps you mickylarson.

Answer (score 1):

After you installed rJava and JDK >1.4, check whether the path variable to Java is set correctly. Then do:

```
R CMD javareconf
```

at the command line for configuration of R with java support. After this rj should install just fine.

Comment: It just says:

'javareconf' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: C:\Program Files\R\R-2.11.1-x64\bin>java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: INSIDE R       > library(rJava)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dirname(this$RuntimeLib)
  error: a character vector argument expected
Error: package/namespace load failed for 'rJava'

Answer (score 0):

For Win 7(64Bit) & R x64 environment, you must install a JRE 64bit image. I did also encounter this issue when I use R x64 but only install JRE 32bit, but when I switch to R i386 window, this issue was gone.